# How to switch from Path to os.path and vice versa?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib, os.path

Whenever I want to work with files or directories, the approach of today is to use `pathlib`.
`pathlib` is great, convenient, easy to use, and OS independent.

However, some libraries still expect me to use `os.path`.
How can I transform my `Path` to the old-school version?

What should I do with my `p` in the following example?

```py
from pathlib import Path

p = Path.cwd()
some_old_function(p)   # <---- error
```

Comment: Why not just convert it to string?

Comment: Can you give a specific example where this fails? Most functions now accept `PathLike` objects

Comment: shutil.move() is a good example. It fails with error ''PosixPath' object has no attribute 'rstrip'' when you pass pathlib.Path object in the method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phrase *some libraries still expect me to use `os.path`* seem to confuse you. `os.path` is a module that simply treats paths as ***strings*** - as opposed to `pathlib` which treats them as specialized objects in the OOP approach.

To create an easy and well-defined transition between the two representations, [PEP 519](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0519) was introduced in Python 3.6. It introduces a new abstract class - [`PathLike`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.PathLike) - and a new `os` function - [`fspath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.fspath). Any API/library that wishes to implement a path object (`pathlib` included), should inherit `PathLike` and implement the `__fspath__` method (which will be called by `os.fspath`).

[The main rationale](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0519/#rationale) for this is that using `str(path)` is error-prone - many objects have a string representation (`str(None)` gives `"None"`), but they should not all be treated as paths.

Specifically for `pathlib` (at the time of writing this), [the implementation of `__fspath__` is basically just a wrapper over `str()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2e3e0d23adca8d83722d939d6abd1e467d7578f7/Lib/pathlib.py#L629), but you should still arguably prefer to use it in case it ever changes in the future.

Note that you don't need to actually call `os.fspath` when passing an argument to most built-in functions. Most `os.path` functions were changed to accept `PathLike`s instead of strings and already use `os.fspath` on it (can be seen in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#module-os.path) as *Changed in version 3.6: Accepts a path-like object.* under most functions). So you can simply pass a `Path` object as-is to most of them.

Comment: I have heard it's better practice to use `fspath(path)`.https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0519/#id17

Comment: @mattalxndr All `__fspath__` does [is call `str()` on the path](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2e3e0d23adca8d83722d939d6abd1e467d7578f7/Lib/pathlib.py#L629) so it feels weird to `import os` and call `os.fspath` when you can just use (the built-in) `str`... Is there another benefit of using `fspath` I am missing?

Comment: When you call `fspath(path)`, you're being explicit. You need a file system path. Say some random lib next to yours in `site-packages` mucked around with `PurePath.__str__()`. If you're using `str(p)`, that's your code broken. On the other hand, if they mess up `fspath(p)`, that's *their* code broken.

Comment: I realize that they are both defined in the docs, but people override `__str__` all the time. `__fspath__`, less so. Also, it might be a simple map right now, but that might change. Or another another class inheriting `PurePath` might be included in stdlib that does something different.

Comment: @mattalxndr very interesting. I wasn't actually aware of `fspath` before. I will add it to the answer shortly. Thank you

Comment: @mattalxndr Thank you again. I went over that PEP in detail and it was a very interesting read! See my (vastly) updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Just convert it to string.

```py
from pathlib import Path
p = Path.cwd()
some_old_function(str(p))
```

Now I also understand, why it was necessary to introduce `pathlib`...

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your PosixPath to a string, os.path expect a string. You can use as_posix or str.

```
In [1]: from pathlib import Path

In [2]: Path.cwd()
Out[2]: PosixPath('/usr/home/ericbsd')

In [3]: Path.cwd().as_posix()
Out[3]: '/usr/home/ericbsd'

In [4]: str(Path.cwd())
Out[4]: '/usr/home/ericbsd
```

here how it would look like with as_posix.

```
from pathlib import Path
p = Path.cwd().as_posix()
some_old_function(p)
```

As for converting os.path to pathlib you can use PosixPath.

```
In [1]: from pathlib import PosixPath

In [2]: import os

In [3]: os.getcwd()
Out[3]: '/usr/home/ericbsd'

In [4]: PosixPath(os.getcwd())
Out[4]: PosixPath('/usr/home/ericbsd')
```